# Переполнение памяти при парсинге таблицы из файла txt

Tags: c#, парсер, память, переполнение

из текстового файла парсятся данные, большое количество, происходит переполнение памяти.
output - это все символы текстового файла. В чем может быть причина переполнения памяти ?

```
private List<Dictionary<string,dynamic>> GetIsqlResult(string query, List<int> widths=null)
{
            var result = new List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>();

            
            var num = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            var tempNameCom = $"isql_command_{num}.bat";
            var tempNameScr = $"isql_script_{num}.bat";
            var tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
            var tempFileCommand = Path.Combine(tempPath, tempNameCom);
            var tempFileScript = Path.Combine(tempPath, tempNameScr);


            if (File.Exists(tempFileCommand))
            {
                File.Delete(tempFileCommand);
            }
            if (File.Exists(tempFileScript))
            {
                File.Delete(tempFileScript);
            }


            File.WriteAllText(tempFileCommand, "\"C:\\Program Files");

            File.WriteAllText(tempFileScript, "QUIT");

           

            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = tempFileCommand;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            p.Start();
            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();

            File.Delete(tempFileCommand);
            File.Delete(tempFileScript);

            File.WriteAllText(Path.ChangeExtension(tempFileScript, ".txt"), output);

           
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(output.Trim()))
            {
                output = output.Replace("<null>","      ");

                var lines = output.Split(new char[] { '\n' });
              //  var widths = new List<int>();
                var names = new List<string>();

                var preline = "";

                foreach (var line in lines)
                {

                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                    {
                        if (line.Contains("==="))
                        {
                            if (widths == null)
                            {
                                widths = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.Length).ToList();
                            }

                            var pos = 0;
                            foreach (var width in widths)
                            {
                                var name = preline.Substring(pos, width).Trim();

                                pos += width + 1;
                               
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                                {
                                    names.Add(name);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                       
                        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && names.Count > 0)
                        {
                            var dict = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

                            var pos = 0;
                            foreach (var name in names)
                            {
                                var width = widths[names.IndexOf(name)];
                                dict[name] = line.Substring(pos, width).Trim();
                                pos += width + 1;
                            }

                            result.Add(dict);
                        }

                        preline = line;
                    }
                }


            }

            return result;
}
```

Comment: Для начала покажите весь код, а не кусок неизвестно чего, где даже работы с файлом нет. Еще расскажите, что делает этот код, чтобы не пришлось угадывать.

Comment: добавили код, Он парсит данные из текстового файла. В текстовом файле расположена таблица. Ее данные нужно получить

Comment: А таблица откуда взялась? Не из БД ли? Почему бы не прочитать данные из БД напрямую, а не вот это вот всё?

Comment: Таблица из базы данных, напрямую читать не могу. Могу только править код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, поехали. Видел бы я таблицу своими глазами, точнее ее форматирование, быть может еще код упростил.

- `WriteAllText` перезаписывает файл полностью, нет нужды предварительно его удалять.
- Данные, полученные из потока процесса можно сразу записать в файл прямо консольными средствами `p.StartInfo.Arguments = "> file.txt";`. Где `>` перезаписывает файл, `>>` добавляет вывод в конец файла.
- Затем файл этот читать построчно через энумератор `File.ReadLines`
- `List<Dictionary<string,dynamic>>` выглядит как таблица данных. Есть же `System.Data.DataTable`, специально для этого предназначенная.
- Я не нашел здесь ни одной причины для использования `dynamic`.
- Там где не надо модифицировать список (добавлять и удалять из него элементы), используйте массив.
- Ну и проверок лишних налепили там, где не надо.

В итоге, данные полностью вычитываются только в `DataTable`, копий в строках нет и не должно быть.

```
private DataTable GetIsqlResult(string query, int[] widths = null)
{
    var data = new DataTable();
    var num = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    var tempNameCom = $"isql_command_{num}.bat";
    var tempNameScr = $"isql_script_{num}.bat";
    var tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
    var tempFileCommand = Path.Combine(tempPath, tempNameCom);
    var tempFileScript = Path.Combine(tempPath, tempNameScr);
    var txtPath = Path.ChangeExtension(tempFileScript, ".txt");

    File.WriteAllText(tempFileCommand, @"C:\Program Files");
    File.WriteAllText(tempFileScript, "QUIT");

    var p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/c \"{tempFileCommand}\" > \"{txtPath}\"";

    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();

    File.Delete(tempFileCommand);
    File.Delete(tempFileScript);

    var preline = string.Empty;

    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(txtPath).Select(l => l.Trim().Replace("<null>", "      ")).Where(l => l.Length > 0))
    {
        if (line.Contains("==="))
        {
            if (widths == null)
            {
                widths = line.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.Length).ToArray();
            }

            var pos = 0;
            foreach (var width in widths)
            {
                var name = preline.Substring(pos, width).Trim();
                var column = data.Columns.Add(name);
                column.DataType = typeof(string);
                pos += width + 1;
            }
        }
        else if (data.Columns.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRow row = data.NewRow();
            var pos = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                var width = widths[i];
                row[i] = line.Substring(pos, width).Trim();
                pos += width + 1;
            }
            data.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        preline = line;
    }

    File.Delete(txtPath);
    return data;
}
```

Как работать с `DataTable`, я думаю, разберетесь.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Очень помогли!